# Margins play spoilsport with figures in exsheets question

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, margins, exsheets

I am designing question papers. Several of these question contains graphs and I would like to format the graph in right half space of the question. I am using `exsheets` package for writing the questions and `TikZ` to produce the graphs. Points are displayed via stars and are supposed to be displayed in the margins. Everything works well if there are no graphs. If however I include graphs, all hell breaks loose.

I tried using `wrapfig` and `cutwin` packages too but the results are even worse. Finally I tried writing my homemade "wrapping" command using `minipage`. This is also extremely jarring.

I see several problems with it

1. The question marker "QB [2]" is not displayed at the start of the questions.
2. The text of the second question is indented very differently from the first question.
3. The stars of the second question too doesn't play well.
4. I have the ugliness of carving out an extra 15% to accommodate the question marker "QB [2]".

   ```
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\textwidth-.15\textwidth\relax}
   ```

The full MWE is here :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rowpoints}[1]{[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}

\SetupExSheets{counter-format=QB [qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rowpoints}

\newcommand{\wraparound}[3]{
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\linewidth-.15\linewidth\relax}
        #2
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}%
        #3
    \end{minipage}%
}%

\begin{document}

    \begin{question}{3}
        A meaningless question without graphs. This looks nice and the next one is supposed to look the same.
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}{2}
    \wraparound{.5}{
        Let me write here a meaningless question with a meaningless graph.
        }{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$a (ms^2)$};
        \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$t (s)$};
        \foreach \ini [evaluate=\ini as \inieval using 2*\ini] in {0,...,1}
        \draw (\inieval,-1) -- ++(0,2) -| (\inieval+1,-1) -- (\inieval+2,-1);
        \draw (1pt, 1) -- (-1pt, 1) node[anchor = east] {$1$};
        \draw (1pt, -1) -- (-1pt, -1) node[anchor = east] {$-1$};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
        \draw (\x cm, 1pt) -- (\x cm, -1pt) node[anchor = north] {$\x$};
        \draw (4,0.5) node[align=left] {$\cdots$};
        \end{tikzpicture}}

        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            (\textit{a}) & $\sin\theta_1 < \sin\theta_2$ & (\textit{b}) & $\sin\theta_1 > \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{c}) & $\sin\theta_1 = \sin\theta_2$ & (\textit{d}) & $\sin^2\theta_1 > \sin^2\theta_2$
        \end{tabular}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Can I rectify these problems? Any suggestions?

An image of the same:

[image: Changed image as per the comment]

Comment: Apart from wrong coding (spurious spaces and \textwidth instead of \linewidth): It simply doesn't fit. The tabular and the graph together are larger than the available space.

Comment: The problem is not the spaces, but the margins not turning out correct (i.e, in the same line as the start of the second question). 
Anyway, question edited to adjust spaces. The four problems I identified remain.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Actually, \linewidth and \textwidth are exactly the same.  This is not a list environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the entire question inside a minpage, but if you reduce the width, the [**] thingy gets moved.  So instead I used `\rightskip` to reserve space for the figure.  First, you need to know how big it is, hence the savebox.  Then you use `\llap` and `\raisebox` to overlay the figure in the reserved space.

I also tried using wrapfigure, but it treated the tabular as a single line of text and continued indenting past the end of the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\newsavebox{\wrapbox}

\newcommand{\rowpoints}[1]{[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}

\SetupExSheets{counter-format=QB [qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rowpoints}

\begin{document}

    \begin{question}{3}
        A meaningless question without graphs. This looks nice and the next one is supposed to look the same.
    \end{question}

    \savebox{\wrapbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$a (ms^2)$};
        \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$t (s)$};
        \foreach \ini [evaluate=\ini as \inieval using 2*\ini] in {0,...,1}
        \draw (\inieval,-1) -- ++(0,2) -| (\inieval+1,-1) -- (\inieval+2,-1);
        \draw (1pt, 1) -- (-1pt, 1) node[anchor = east] {$1$};
        \draw (1pt, -1) -- (-1pt, -1) node[anchor = east] {$-1$};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
        \draw (\x cm, 1pt) -- (\x cm, -1pt) node[anchor = north] {$\x$};
        \draw (4,0.5) node[align=left] {$\cdots$};
        \draw[green] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapbox+\columnsep\relax
      \begin{question}{2}
        Let me write here a meaningless question with a meaningless graph.

        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            (\textit{a}) & $\sin\theta_1 < \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{b}) & $\sin\theta_1 > \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{c}) & $\sin\theta_1 = \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{d}) & $\sin^2\theta_1 > \sin^2\theta_2$
        \end{tabular}
    \end{question}
    \end{minipage}\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapbox}{\usebox{\wrapbox}}}%

    \begin{question}{3}
        A meaningless question without graphs. This looks nice and the next one is supposed to look the same.
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

---

This version centers the figure to the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\newsavebox{\wrapbox}

\newcommand{\rowpoints}[1]{[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}

\SetupExSheets{counter-format=QB [qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rowpoints}

\begin{document}

    \begin{question}{3}
        A meaningless question without graphs. This looks nice and the next one is supposed to look the same.
    \end{question}

    \savebox{\wrapbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$a (ms^2)$};
        \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$t (s)$};
        \foreach \ini [evaluate=\ini as \inieval using 2*\ini] in {0,...,1}
        \draw (\inieval,-1) -- ++(0,2) -| (\inieval+1,-1) -- (\inieval+2,-1);
        \draw (1pt, 1) -- (-1pt, 1) node[anchor = east] {$1$};
        \draw (1pt, -1) -- (-1pt, -1) node[anchor = east] {$-1$};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
        \draw (\x cm, 1pt) -- (\x cm, -1pt) node[anchor = north] {$\x$};
        \draw (4,0.5) node[align=left] {$\cdots$};
        \draw[green] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
      \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapbox+\columnsep\relax
      \begin{question}{2}
        Let me write here a meaningless question with a meaningless graph.

        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            (\textit{a}) & $\sin\theta_1 < \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{b}) & $\sin\theta_1 > \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{c}) & $\sin\theta_1 = \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{d}) & $\sin^2\theta_1 > \sin^2\theta_2$
        \end{tabular}
    \end{question}
    \end{minipage}\llap{\raisebox{-0.5\ht\wrapbox}{\usebox{\wrapbox}}}%

    \begin{question}{3}
        A meaningless question without graphs. This looks nice and the next one is supposed to look the same.
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. This even avoids manually inputting the size of figure. As good as ``wrapfig`` command.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:

I managed to rectify problems 1 and 3 using `adjustbox` package. Now only weird indents and problem 4 remain.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz,adjustbox}

\newcommand{\rowpoints}[1]{[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}

\SetupExSheets{counter-format=QB [qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rowpoints}

\newcommand{\wraparound}[3]{
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1\linewidth-.15\linewidth\relax}
        #2
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill%
    \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{#1\linewidth}%
        #3
    \end{minipage}}%
}%

\begin{document}

    \begin{question}{3}
        A meaningless question without graphs. This looks nice and the next one is supposed to look the same.
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}{2}
    \wraparound{.5}{
        Let me write here a meaningless question with a meaningless graph.
        }{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$a (ms^2)$};
        \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$t (s)$};
        \foreach \ini [evaluate=\ini as \inieval using 2*\ini] in {0,...,1}
        \draw (\inieval,-1) -- ++(0,2) -| (\inieval+1,-1) -- (\inieval+2,-1);
        \draw (1pt, 1) -- (-1pt, 1) node[anchor = east] {$1$};
        \draw (1pt, -1) -- (-1pt, -1) node[anchor = east] {$-1$};
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
        \draw (\x cm, 1pt) -- (\x cm, -1pt) node[anchor = north] {$\x$};
        \draw (4,0.5) node[align=left] {$\cdots$};
        \end{tikzpicture}}

        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            (\textit{a}) & $\sin\theta_1 < \sin\theta_2$ & (\textit{b}) & $\sin\theta_1 > \sin\theta_2$ \\
            (\textit{c}) & $\sin\theta_1 = \sin\theta_2$ & (\textit{d}) & $\sin^2\theta_1 > \sin^2\theta_2$
        \end{tabular}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]