# A template environment to wrap firgures or tables

Tags: environments, expansion

I need to generate several `\newenvironment`s, one for each of my `\newtheorem` as well as exsheets `question`s. however the problem I want to describe is not specific to exsheets. Each of my newenvironments must be able to wrap around a figure. I have already successfully wrapped `question` environment as follows -

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387448/26682
\newsavebox{\wrapquestionfigure}
\newenvironment{wrapquestion}[2]{ % #1 = points, #2 = figure, body = text of question
    \savebox{\wrapquestionfigure}{#2}%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
    \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapquestionfigure+\columnsep\relax%
    \question{#1}%
}{
    \endquestion%
    \endminipage\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapquestionfigure}{\usebox{\wrapquestionfigure}}}%%
}
```

It works flawlessly. Now I wish to do the same for wrapping  `\newtheorem`s. My idea is to create a template `\newenvironment` to which I will pass the name of the environment `X` as well as arguments. If (atmost one) argument `<arg>` is empty, it will call `\X`, otherwise `\X{<arg>}`.

This is the code --

```
% new environment based on the above -- to wrap a figure or table around evironment X
\newenvironment{wrapfiginenv}[3]{ 
    % #1 = environment X (question/thm/fact/ex/exc/exercise) 
    % #2 = arguments of that particular environment X (empty if none), 
    % #3 = figure or table 
    % body = body of environment X
    \savebox{\wrapquestionfigure}{#3}%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
    \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapquestionfigure+\columnsep\relax%
    \ifthenelse{ \euqal{#2}{} } {
        \csname #1\endcsname
    } {
        \csname #1\leftbracechar#2\rightbracechar\endcsname
    }
}{
    \def\tmpcmd{end}
    \expandafter\csname\expandafter\tmpcmd{}#1\endcsname
    \endminipage\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapquestionfigure}{\usebox{\wrapquestionfigure}}}%%
}
```

Whatever permutation of the following I try

```
\def\tmpcmd{end}
\expandafter\csname\expandafter\tmpcmd{}#1\endcsname
```

It doesnt work. Where am I going wrong?

This is an MWE --

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsthm,adjustbox,tikz,ifthen} 
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets} 

% new commands for wrapping questions
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387448/26682
\newsavebox{\wrapquestionfigure}

\newenvironment{wrapquestion}[2]{ % #1 = points, #2 = figure, body = text of question
    \savebox{\wrapquestionfigure}{#2}%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
    \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapquestionfigure+\columnsep\relax%
    \question{#1}%
}{
    \endquestion%
    \endminipage\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapquestionfigure}{\usebox{\wrapquestionfigure}}}%%
}

% new environment based on the above -- to wrap a figure or table around evironment X
\newenvironment{wrapfiginenv}[3]{ 
    % #1 = environment X (question/thm/fact/ex/exc/exercise) 
    % #2 = arguments of that particular environment X (empty if none), 
    % #3 = figure or table 
    % body = body of environment X
    \savebox{\wrapquestionfigure}{#3}%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
    \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapquestionfigure+\columnsep\relax%
    \ifthenelse{ \euqal{#2}{} } {
        \csname #1\endcsname
    } {
        \csname #1\leftbracechar#2\rightbracechar\endcsname
    }
}{
    %\def\tmpcmd{end}
    %\expandafter\csname\expandafter\tmpcmd{}#1\endcsname
    \endminipage\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapquestionfigure}{\usebox{\wrapquestionfigure}}}%%
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{fact}[thm]{Fact} % there are several more such environments

\begin{document}
    \begin{fact}
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
                Using the adjoining table and we can compute cross products of any vector as demonstrated in the classroom.
        \end{minipage}}%
        \hfill%
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tabular}{|cc|}
                        $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}=\hat{k}$ & $\hat{j}\times\hat{i}=-\hat{k}$ \\
                        $\hat{j}\times\hat{k}=\hat{i}$ & $\hat{k}\times\hat{j}=-\hat{i}$ \\
                        $\hat{k}\times\hat{i}=\hat{j}$ & $\hat{i}\times\hat{k}=-\hat{j}$ \\
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{center}
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{fact}

    \begin{wrapquestion}{1}{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$a (ms^2)$};
            \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$t (s)$};
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        If  $\vec{C}=\alpha\vec{A}+\beta\vec{B}$  then $\vec{A}\cdot(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})+ \vec{B}\cdot(\vec{C}\times\vec{A}) + \vec{C}\cdot(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$
    \end{wrapquestion}

    % the idea is to make the following work just like the question above.
    %\begin{wrapfiginenv}{fact}{}{\begin{tabular}{|cc|}%
    %               $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}=\hat{k}$ & $\hat{j}\times\hat{i}=-\hat{k}$ \\
    %               $\hat{j}\times\hat{k}=\hat{i}$ & $\hat{k}\times\hat{j}=-\hat{i}$ \\
    %               $\hat{k}\times\hat{i}=\hat{j}$ & $\hat{i}\times\hat{k}=-\hat{j}$ \\
    %           \end{tabular}}
    %   Using the adjoining table and  we can compute cross products of any vector as demonstrated in the classroom.
    %\end{wrapfiginenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I must say that the first solution was proposed by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387448/26682

Comment: it is much easier to debug code if you supply it as a complete document that can be run and tested. For example `\ifthenelse{ \euqal{` has a presumably undefined command `\euqal`

Comment: perhaps you want `\csname #1\leftbracechar#2\rightbracechar\endcsname` to be `\csname #1\endcsname{#2}` but it's hard to guess the intended meaning of this construct

Comment: added an MWE. please see

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ``\csname #1\leftbracechar#2\rightbracechar\endcsname`` is intended to mean ``\#1{#2}``. Meaning for ``\begin{wrapfiginenv}{question}{12}``, it should call ``\question{#2}``.

Comment: so you don't want `{#2}` inside the csname!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\def\tmpcmd{end}
\expandafter\csname\expandafter\tmpcmd{}#1\endcsname
```

The sequence of `\expandafter`s expand `{`  but this is a non expandable token so it doesn't expand.

So this is the same as

```
 \csname end{#1}\endcsname
```

which generates a csname with `{` in its name which is almost certainly not going to have been defined so it will act as `\relax`.

You presumably want

```
 \csname end#1\endcsname
```

which will execute `\endproof` if `#1` is `proof`  or simpler you could use

```
 \end{#1}
```

and use `\begin{#1}` to start the environment.

---

With the MWE now supplied, if you uncomment the second environment you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text>  \euqal
```

presumably `\equal` was intended. Then fixing the csname usage as above leads to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsthm,adjustbox,tikz,ifthen} 
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets} 

% new commands for wrapping questions
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387448/26682
\newsavebox{\wrapquestionfigure}

\newenvironment{wrapquestion}[2]{ % #1 = points, #2 = figure, body = text of question
    \savebox{\wrapquestionfigure}{#2}%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
    \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapquestionfigure+\columnsep\relax%
    \question{#1}%
}{
    \endquestion%
    \endminipage\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapquestionfigure}{\usebox{\wrapquestionfigure}}}%%
}

% new environment based on the above -- to wrap a figure or table around evironment X
\newenvironment{wrapfiginenv}[3]{%%%%<
    % #1 = environment X (question/thm/fact/ex/exc/exercise) 
    % #2 = arguments of that particular environment X (empty if none), 
    % #3 = figure or table 
    % body = body of environment X
    \savebox{\wrapquestionfigure}{#3}%
    \noindent\minipage[t]{\textwidth}%
    \rightskip=\dimexpr \wd\wrapquestionfigure+\columnsep\relax%
    \def\thisname{#1}%
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#2}{} } {%%%%<
        \csname #1\endcsname
    } {%%%%<
        \csname #1\endcsname{#2}%%%%<
    }%%%%<
}{%%%%<
    \csname end\thisname\endcsname
    \endminipage\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox-\ht\wrapquestionfigure}{\usebox{\wrapquestionfigure}}}%%
}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{fact}[thm]{Fact} % there are several more such environments

\begin{document}
    \begin{fact}
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
                Using the adjoining table and we can compute cross products of any vector as demonstrated in the classroom.
        \end{minipage}}%
        \hfill%
        \adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tabular}{|cc|}
                        $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}=\hat{k}$ & $\hat{j}\times\hat{i}=-\hat{k}$ \\
                        $\hat{j}\times\hat{k}=\hat{i}$ & $\hat{k}\times\hat{j}=-\hat{i}$ \\
                        $\hat{k}\times\hat{i}=\hat{j}$ & $\hat{i}\times\hat{k}=-\hat{j}$ \\
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{center}
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{fact}

    \begin{wrapquestion}{1}{\begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) node[above] {$a (ms^2)$};
            \draw[->] (-.3,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$t (s)$};
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        If  $\vec{C}=\alpha\vec{A}+\beta\vec{B}$  then $\vec{A}\cdot(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})+ \vec{B}\cdot(\vec{C}\times\vec{A}) + \vec{C}\cdot(\vec{A}\times\vec{B})$
    \end{wrapquestion}

    % the idea is to make the following work just like the question above.
    \begin{wrapfiginenv}{fact}{}{\begin{tabular}{|cc|}%
                   $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}=\hat{k}$ & $\hat{j}\times\hat{i}=-\hat{k}$ \\
                   $\hat{j}\times\hat{k}=\hat{i}$ & $\hat{k}\times\hat{j}=-\hat{i}$ \\
                   $\hat{k}\times\hat{i}=\hat{j}$ & $\hat{i}\times\hat{k}=-\hat{j}$ \\
               \end{tabular}}
       Using the adjoining table and  we can compute cross products of any vector as demonstrated in the classroom.
    \end{wrapfiginenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: using ``\csname end#1\endcsname`` or ``\end{#1}`` produces a compile error ``Illegal parameter number in definition of \endwrapfiginenv. }``. Frankly it baffles me.

Comment: @magguu oh well yes you can't pass an enviornment argument to the end code of an enviornment definition that is just standard `\newenvironment` behaviour. I showed how to construct `\endproof{#1}` given `\proof` if you execute that a place where `\endproof{#1}` is not allowed then of course you get an error.

Comment: @magguu see update

Comment: wow! it works. thank a lot! could you please explain why it does work?

Comment: @magguu I thought I explained above, it works as I fixed all the errors;-) \equal spelling, \csname usage and also you have to save `#1` in the begin code in a macro to use it in the end code.

Comment: My excitement was a bit premature. Though ``\begin{wrapfiginenv}{question}`` works as expected, ``\begin{wrapfiginenv}{fact}`` still does not work. The error becomes apparent if one uses a large body of text inside the environment. I guess the reason is that theorem environments are technically lists. maybe I need to use ``cutwin`` package to make it work.

Comment: @magguu you gave no indication of what you wanted the code to do. As far as I can tell it was just putting the argument and the body side by side in adjacent boxes (it seems a complicated way of doing that). I fixed the tex errors. If by this comment you mean that you want the text to wrap around the content then this is not going to work.